# Unlocking bootloader LG G6 Verizon

Tags: rooting, bootloader, lg, verizon

1. I'm not able to get fastboot to respond to any commands
2. There is no OEM Unlock Option visible in the Developer Options Screen
3. LG's [tool](http://developer.lge.com/resource/mobile/RetrieveBootloader.dev) does not support the LG G6

Are there other options I should be exploring?

Comment: Once again: your own fault for buying anything Verizon. LG is also partly to blame here as they themselves won't unlock anything not from europe or T-Mobile either. This is just policy.